# How to reexport std::source_location with modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm starting to use modules in my code and tried to create a simple exported function in a module using `std::source_location`. However, compilation fails at the function call stating `error: ‘source_location’ is not a member of ‘std’`.
This is the code in question:

util.cpp:

```
module;

#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>

export module util;

export using source_loc = std::source_location;

export void panic(const char* message, const source_loc loc = source_loc::current()) {
    std::cout << "file: "
              << loc.file_name() << "(" << loc.line() << ":" << loc.column() << ") `"
              << loc.function_name() << "`: " << message << '\n';
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
import util;

int main() {
    panic("oh noez"); // < compiler error here
}
```

The compiler gives a hint about forgetting to `#include <source_location>` and indeed if I add it to main.cpp it compiles and works as expected. Except I already exported `std::source_location` as `source_loc` from my `util`-module so I would expect it to be accessible in `main`because of the `import util` statement. Having to explicitly `#include <source_location>` everywhere I use the defined `panic` function seems to defeat the very purpose of modules altogether.

What is going on here? Am I missing something essential about C++ modules? Or did I simply make a mistake that is easily fixed?

I'm using g++ 11.2 to compile the code like this: `g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts util.cpp main.cpp -o main`

Answer (score 0):

This now compiles with gcc 12.2 and Visual Studio 2022 (17.3.6) (the latter when enabling experimental features)

https://godbolt.org/z/89jb7cP5G

I think gcc has been fixed since then and I think your code is correct too.